# eloquent one-To-Many-To-Many

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

Hi everyone I start with Laravel and eloquent and already I have a problem.

I have users, each user can have multiple vehicles and a vehicle can have multiple rentals. I want to list all rentals of each vehicle belonging to the current user.

User model:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];


    public function vehicule()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Vehicule');
    }
```

Vehicule model:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Vehicule extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [

    'user_id',
    'published',
    'rented'
];


public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function rental()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Rental');
}
```

Rental model:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Rental extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [
        'from_date',
        'to_date',
        'amount_total',
        'vehicule_id'
    ];


    public function vehicule()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Vehicule');
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried already to list each user with their vehicles and rentals?

Comment: I listed the vehicles now I want the list of rentals for each vehicle rentals for each vehicle and send them to view

Comment: Could you add the view file as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your existing relationships:

```php
$rentals = $user->load('vehicule.rental')->pluck('vehicule.rental')->collapse();
```

Or add a [`HasManyThrough`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relationship to `User`:

```php
public function rental()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Rental::class, Vehicule::class);
}

$rentals = $user->rental;
```